# turning on off samsung secure folder programmatically android java api

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk, samsung-knox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paVUz.png)

Is it possible to turn on off (hide) the samsung secure folder through code in android java? Is there any Api or other way to do this function from another app?

I want to create an android app that connects to internet and it has a simple socket.io that gets the turn on / off (hide/unhide) command from server and hides or unhides the devices secure folder.

is it possible?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samsung secure folder is a proprietary feature from Samsung OEM. They do not provide any api to any third party application to do any changes to this or any of there features. Any hack that you may devise would be temporary and futile as they are quite active in  terminating such attempts.